# How to change a regular image to a Rect in pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, rect

I need the simplest way of making an image a Rect, is there a function for this or do I need to make it a Rect from the beginning? I have a script were the player moves around but I want the image of the character to be a Rect, so I can do more with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I want the image of the character to be a rect* doesn't make a lot of sense, but you're probably looking for the [`get_rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) method of the [`Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) class:

> **get_rect()**
>   *get the rectangular area of the Surface*
>   `get_rect(**kwargs) -> Rect`
>   Returns a new rectangle covering the entire surface. This rectangle will always start at 0, 0 with a width. and height the same size as the image...

(I guess with *regular image* you mean a `Surface`, since a `Surface` is how pygame represents images)

Note that the `Rect` returned by this function always starts at `0`, `0`. If you already track the position of your object somehow (say a `x` and `y` variable), you could either

- drop those variables and only use a `Rect` to keep track of the position of your object. If you move your object, instead of altering the `x` and `y` variable (e.g. `x += mx`/`y += my`), you would just update the `Rect` (e.g. `pos.move_ip(mx, my)` where `pos` is the `Rect`).
- create a new `Rect` whenever you need a `Rect`, and make sure it points to the right location, using named arguments (e.g. `your_surface.get_rect(x=x, y=y)`)
- use a [`Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), which is basically a combination of a `Surface` and a `Rect`.